# How can I blur everything behind the modal? filter: blur(1px) blurs everything including the modal

Tags: html, css, sass

I tried these codes in CSS (SASS) but they don't work. They blur everything, including the modal. I just want to blur the background when the modal is open. What should I do?

```
.modal-open
    overflow: hidden

    &:not(.modal)
        filter: blur(2px)
```

or this

```
.modal-open
    overflow: hidden
    filter: blur(2px)
```

or this

```
.modal-open:not(.modal)
    filter: blur(2px)
```

JS (React):

```
if (this.state.showModalSuz) {
            document.body.classList.add('modal-open');
        }
        if (!this.state.showModalSuz) {
            document.body.classList.remove('modal-open');
        }
```

Comment: AFAIK, this is not valid CSS. You are missing curly braces `{`, `}`. Also, I'm not aware of a selector `&`. Apart from that, can you provide a working example of your issue?

Comment: I'm using SASS, sorry.

Comment: https://codepen.io/t4lh4z/pen/xxKgxYB?editors=0110 like here the first example

Comment: your modal needs to be seperate to the element you want to apply the blur to i.e. in a separate tree

Comment: And by _separate_ I believe @ImmortalDude means it can't be a child of the element to be blurred. Which means you probably want to have the modal be a direct child of `body`. This way, you can apply a blur to `main` - or whatever is your page wrapper, if any - without affecting the modal.